# Mybatis and JSF 2.0 integration, error when loading data into a list

Tags: jsf, datatable, mybatis

I am writing a simple CRUD application (I'm using JSF 2.0 and mybatis3 on an oracle database) and so far I encountered an error while displaying the data (in a ) that I queried. I know this is really messy but I'd love some advice to what I am doing wrong. Thanks !

**EDIT 1:** I also made a plain java project and tested out the functions to see if they retunr anything or not and it worked properly...

**EDIt 2:** Log here, no errors tho  http://pastebin.com/gYyqBX7W

Here is the a part from UserMapper.xml:

```
<resultMap id="result" type="User">
    <result property="username" column="USER_ID" />
    <result property="userDescription" column="USER_DESC" />
    <result property="password" column="USER_PWD" />
</resultMap>

<select id="getAllUsers" resultMap="result"> 
SELECT USER_ID as username, USER_DESC as userDescription,
    USER_PWD as password FROM SSLS_GUI.USERS
</select>
```

the UserMapper.java file:

```
package com.mybatis.mappers;
import java.util.List;
import com.optsol.beans.User;

public interface UserMapper {

public List<User> getAllUsers();

}
```

The part from UserService.java that intrests me:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userServices")
public class UserService {
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    SqlSession sqlSession = MyBatisUtil.getSqlSessionFactory()
            .openSession();
    try {
        UserMapper userMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
        return userMapper.getAllUsers();
    } finally {
        sqlSession.close();
    }
}
```

The MyBatisUtil.java file where I get the factory instance from:

```
package com.mybatis.service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

import org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder;

public class MyBatisUtil {
private static SqlSessionFactory factory;

private MyBatisUtil() {
}

    static {
    String resource = "com/mybatis/config/mybatis-config.xml";
    Reader reader = null;
    try {

        reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
    factory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
}

    public static SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory() {
    return factory;
}
}
```

The User.java (without the getters and setters):

```
package com.optsol.beans;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
@ManagedBean(name = "user")
public class User {

    private String username;
    private String userDescription;
    private String password;
}
```

The index.xhtml where I try to display the data from the database:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{userService.getAllUsers}" var="u">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
                USERNAME
            </f:facet>
                #{u.username}
        </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
                USER DESCRIPTION
            </f:facet>
                #{u.userDescription}
        </h:column>
                <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
                PASSWORD(HASHED)
            </f:facet>
                #{u.password}
        </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @PaulVargas http://pastebin.com/gYyqBX7W I had to put it on pastebin. but I don't really think I caught anything there that gives info about the error...:(

Answer (score 0):

The name of the properties does not match the name of the columns.

```
<resultMap id="result" type="User">
    <result property="username" column="USER_ID" />
    <result property="userDescription" column="USER_DESC" />
    <result property="password" column="USER_PWD" />
</resultMap>
```

Remove the alias in the SQL.

```
<select id="getAllUsers" resultMap="result"> 
    SELECT USER_ID, 
           USER_DESC,
           USER_PWD
      FROM SSLS_GUI.USERS
</select>
```